# Action button in Material UI Autocomplete for No Options

Tags: reactjs, autocomplete, material-ui

I need to implement Material UI's autocomplete in react where when there are no options available, I need to show a button to add a new Option.

I have used the `noOptionsText` to add a new button when there is no matches but the button click doesn't work.
Below is the code I have used.

```
  const [colors, setColors] = useState([{ name: 'red' }, { name: 'yellow' }, { name: 'black' }]);

  <Autocomplete
    options={colors}
    getOptionLabel={(option) => option.name}
    value={values.color}
    renderInput={(params) => (
      <TextField
          // eslint-disable-next-line react/jsx-props-no-spreading
        {...params}
        label="Colors"
        variant="outlined"
        fullWidth
      />
    )}
    noOptionsText={(
      <Box display="flex" justifyContent="space-between" alignItems="center">
        Color not available
        <Button
          variant="outlined"
          color="primary"
          onClick={() => { console.log('Add new color'); }}
        >
        Add New Color
        </Button>
      </Box>
    )}
  />
```

The UI is as follows.

[image]
[image]

When I search for a color which isn't present, The "No Options" is displayed which i have customized to add a button. On Clicking the "Add New Color" the Autocomplete popup simply closes and the button event does not trigger.

Comment: @RyanCogswell , Thanks. Even though my requirement was for the noOptionsText, using onMouseDown instead of OnClick triggers the event. Thanks a ton!

Comment: yep `onMouseDown` is triggered. thanks.