# Material UI Autocomplete create clickable Button in noOptionsText

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm using Material Ui Autocomplete component. I would like that when the user types something, and he gets no results, the `noOptionsText` shows a button that can be clicked to do something:

```
import React from "react";
import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";
import Autocomplete from "@material-ui/lab/Autocomplete";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <Autocomplete
      options={["HELLO", "HI"]}
      renderInput={(params) => (
        <TextField {...params} label="Combo box" variant="outlined" />
      )}
      noOptionsText={
        <Button onClick={() => console.log("CLICK SUCCESSFUL")}>
          No results! Click me
        </Button>
      }
    />
  );
}
```

Here the button appears successfully, but then when I click it the Autocomplete is closed before the button can receive the click.

It works if I set `debug={true}` to force keep the menu open, but this have many other side effects.
Tried also forcing `open={true}` but it still gets closed.

How would you do that?

Codesandbox demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/vigilant-haslett-sngyb?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you click the button in the no-option menu, the `TextField` is blurred (unfocused), you can know that by logging reason in `onClose` callback

```
onClose={(e, reason) => {
  console.log("on close", reason);
}}
```

The only way to suppress this is to set `debug = true` as documented in Material-UI API [docs](https://material-ui.com/api/autocomplete/#autocomplete-api).

But if you don't want to use `debug`, there is another workaround by making the button part of the option menu itself. Remember unlike the no-option menu, you can register a click in the `Autocomplete` menu to select option normally.

You can do that by filtering the option as usual but if there is no option found, return the button option instead. Here is an example

```
import Autocomplete, { createFilterOptions } from "@material-ui/lab/Autocomplete";

const options = ["HELLO", "HI"];
const buttonOption = (
  <Button
    onClick={(e) => {
      console.log("CLICK SUCCESSFUL");
      e.stopPropagation();
    }}
  >
    No results! Click me
  </Button>
);
const defaultFilterOptions = createFilterOptions();

export default function App() {
  const [selectedOptions, setSelectedOptions] = React.useState("");

  return (
    <Autocomplete
      options={options}
      onChange={(_, value) => {
        if (typeof value === "string") {
          setSelectedOptions(value);
        }
      }}
      renderOption={(o) => o}
      getOptionLabel={(o) => (typeof o === "string" ? o : "")}
      renderInput={(params) => (
        <TextField {...params} label="Combo box" variant="outlined" />
      )}
      filterOptions={(options, state) => {
        const results = defaultFilterOptions(options, state);

        if (results.length === 0) {
          return [buttonOption];
        }

        return results;
      }}
    />
  );
}
```

### Live Demo

[image: Edit Material-UI Autocomplete NoOption Button]

Comment: I found a small bug: when the button appears, I can click either on the button (ok) or on the row outside the button, like if I'm "choosing" the button as an option. In that case I get : The `getOptionLabel` method of Autocomplete returned object ([object Object]).

Comment: @edoedoedo I've fixed the issue in the live demo. The button is not a string like other options so it complains

Answer (score 9):

On Button component, don't use onClick, try onMouseDown like this:

```
  noOptionsText={
    <Button onMouseDown={() => {
        console.log("CLICK SUCCESSFUL")
    }}>
      No results! Click me
    </Button>
```

This is a duplicate of a duplicate: [Action button in Material UI Autocomplete for No Options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59740590/action-button-in-material-ui-autocomplete-for-no-options?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 0):

There is an easy way you have to declare a state let just say "Open" and overwrite the Open prop of Autocomplete, set debug={true}, and when you click on Button in **noOption**, there you can set your Open state to false. In this way, it will close on Button Click.

```
import React from "react";
import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";
import Autocomplete from "@material-ui/lab/Autocomplete";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";

export default function App() {
const [Open, setOpen] = React.useState(true);
  return (
    <Autocomplete
      Open={Open}
      debug={true}
      options={["HELLO", "HI"]}
      renderInput={(params) => (
        <TextField {...params} label="Combo box" variant="outlined" />
      )}
      noOptionsText={
        <Button onClick={() => {
            console.log("CLICK SUCCESSFUL")
            setOpen(false)
        }}>
          No results! Click me
        </Button>
      }
    />
  );
}
```